# How and where to store In-App Purchased “Consumable” products?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, in-app-purchase

Let’s assume we have a game with virtual Coins. The game comes with 10 coins from App Store. There is a possibility to purchase coins 1,3,5,10,100… with different prices. The user spends the Coins during the game.

Questions:

1. Where to store the amount of Coins?
2. How to prevent using preloaded coins after re-installing the application?
3. If we need to store the coins on external server, what device identifier should we use? Is it identifierForVendor? If so, uninstalling the application will change the identifier.
4. Does user expect to have the same Coins on another device? If so, how to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution for this scenario is the in-game account + iCloud:

1. Have the user profile saved as a plist, for example, secure it to prevent manipulation, and sync it to the iCloud.
2. Force the iCloud sync each time the app starts.
3. No need for this as you identify the user by his in-game and iCloud account.
4. Here I'd say the user would expect the same coins on another device as long as he uses the same profile name and the iCloud account.

I can recommend you the iOS5 by tutorials by Ray Wanderlich if you want to learn iCloud programming.
I'm happy to give you some more detailed info if you ask more detailed questions in the comments.

Comment: @lawiko, thank you very much for the recomendation.  
Here is the site [Ray Wanderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) for those who are interested.

Comment: What is 'in-game' account?

Comment: In-game account is a simple account that you use for storing the progress of your game, for example in KingdomRush or PirateLegends you  have 3 slots and need to choose one when you start playing, the game then creates this in-game account for you and saves your progress there, so whenever you quit and enter again you can start playing from where you left off.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to say that according to Apple's In-App Purchase Guidelines...

> "You may not offer items that represent intermediary currency because
>   it is important that users know the specific good or service that they
>   are buying."

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

Comment: This is incorrect. He said "The user spends the Coins during the game.", the OP isn't selling a good or service with the coins, just in-game advantages.

Comment: I stand corrected... "Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the App".  Apparently this IS allowed.  https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies  (see section 11.4)